# xsl navigation doesn't appear to be working

Tags: xml, xslt

I am not sure why this isn't working.

Here is my xml:

```
<s:Body xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<LoginBodyResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org">
<LoginBodyResult>somettext</LoginBodyResult>
</LoginBodyResponse>
</s:Body>
```

Here is my current xsl:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
            xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
            xmlns:var="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/var"
            exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl var s0"
            version="1.0"
            xmlns:ns0="http://tempuri.org"
            xmlns:s0="http://tempuri.org">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="xml" version="1.0" />
<xsl:template match="LoginBodyResponse">
  <ns0:LoginBodyReponse>
    <xsl:if test="LoginBodyResult">
      <LoginBodyResult>
        <xsl:value-of select="LoginBodyResult/text()" />
      </LoginBodyResult>
    </xsl:if>
  </ns0:LoginBodyReponse>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I can't get it to go into this template. I really am not sure why it isn't going to the LoginBodyResponse node. I assume I am making a stupid small mistake, but can't figure out it's problem. I have also set the template match to */ and when I do that, it can never find the LoginBodyResult in the xsl:if section.

I am basically looking for this output:

```
  <ns0:LoginBodyReponse xmlns:ns0="http://tempuri.org">
   <LoginBodyResult>somettest</LoginBodyResult>
  </ns0:LoginBodyReponse>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because `LoginBodyResponse` is in the default namespace `http://tempuri.org`. You're going to need to prefix the elements in your xpaths.

Untested example:

```
<xsl:template match="ns0:LoginBodyResponse">
    <ns0:LoginBodyReponse>
        <xsl:if test="ns0:LoginBodyResult">
            <LoginBodyResult>
                <xsl:value-of select="ns0:LoginBodyResult" />
            </LoginBodyResult>
        </xsl:if>
    </ns0:LoginBodyReponse>
</xsl:template>
```

Also, if you remove your duplicate namespace declaration `xmlns:s0="http://tempuri.org"` (and remove `s0` from `exclude-prefix-results`) you should get the output your looking for.

Comment: duh. That got it. Thanks!

As an aside, the tempuri.org is not really what my xsl looks like. I just changed it to hide my real namespaces on here.